# Webpack - chunk won't loaded

Tags: webpack

i have a problem with webpack chunks

so i configure webpack to compile to dist folder
then there is `buldle.js` and `1.bundle.js` there

but `1.bundle.js` won't be retrived by the browser because the path to the file is wrong

in chrome devtool > network tab

`bundle.js` = `http://localhost:3000/dist/bundle.js`

but..
`1.bundle.js` = `http://localhost:3000/1.bundle.js`

what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer, we need to specify publicPath ..  [Webpack not loading partial files from the same root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803211/webpack-not-loading-partial-files-from-the-same-root)

```
{
    entry: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: 'dist/',
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    }
}
```